# Crear galería de imágenes a partir de un directorio en PHP (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter-3

Buenas, estoy tratando de hacer algo parecido a lo que aparece en la foto de abajo en CSS pero no logro entender bien como lo puedo hacer. Les cuento: tengo un directorio en donde guardo todas las imágenes ej: www.mipagina.cl/imagenes/ y lo que pretendo es mostrar todas esas imágenes en un slider como el de abajo.

[image: Slider]

Estoy trabajando en php con el framework codeigniter y en el código que intenté implementar me aparecía algo como esto:

```
    <div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
        <img data-u="image" src="img/02.jpg" />
        <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-02.jpg" />
    </div>
```

Yo quiero modificar el SRC de todas pero me imagino que no tendre que ir una por una.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Estas utilizando alguna librería para la creación de la galería? A que te refieres con lo de modificar el SRC

Comment: Hola, no estoy utilizando ninguna librería y a lo que me refería con cambiar el src es al source de la etiqueta img, en vez de que vaya esto `<img data-u="image" src="img/02.jpg" />` vaya lo sgte: **`<img data-u="image" src="Ruta de mis imagenes" />`**

Comment: claro de que tienes que modificar esa parte tendrias algo asi `src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>path_img"` te recomiendo que utilices alguna libreria como [http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/] o esta [http://fancybox.net/]

Answer (score 1):

Es necesario usar javascript y css, hay muchos sliders que puedes usar para hacerlo en lo personal uso Owl Carousel http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/

Para que no tengas que llamar una por una las imágenes puedes guardarlas en la base de datos como yo lo hago o puedes hacer un JSON.

En caso que quieras hacerlo desde la base de datos tienes que hacer una funcion en un modelo para que traiga toda la información y mandarla a la vista.

Por Ejemplo:

Suponiendo que tienes una tabla llamada imagenes que tiene las columnas:

id => el id o pk
src => almacena el path y el nombre del archivo

La función de tu modelo puede ser:

```
public function obtenerImagenes(){
$query = $this->db->get('imagenes');
return $query->result_array(); }
```

}

La llamada en el controlador:

```
$this->load->model('tumodelo');
$data['imagenes] = $this->tumodelo->obtenerImagenes();
```

y en tu vista:

```
<div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
    <?php foreach($imagenes as $key): ?>
    <img data-u="thumb" src="<?= $key['src] ?>" />
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

o bien puedes usar la funcion scandir()

```
<div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
<?php $imagenes = scandir('tu_directorio');
foreach ($imagenes as $key => $value) { ?>
     <img data-u="image" src="<?= $value ?>" />
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr lo que propones no es tan relevante qué tecnología utilices del lado del servidor, ya que lo que es necesario es Javascript y CSS, lo que te aconsejo es que utilices alguna biblioteca o plugin, una búsqueda rápida en Google me llevó a esta:

http://www.jssor.com/

Comment: Entiendo perfecto lo que me dices, mi confusión era más que nada por el tema del directorio donde tengo las imágenes ya que son muchas y cada día se van agregando más imágenes, por lo que no se puede hacer de manera manual la inserción de las mismas. Un saludo